# Clicking addRow() causes previous values to disappear

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

addRow() makes the value of the previous rows disappear.

```html
<VDataTable
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :items-per-page="5"
        class="sale-table pa-4"
      >
        <template #item.product="{ item }">
          <div class="d-flex gap-1">
            <VAutocomplete
              v-model="item.product"
              label="Parts"
              density="compact"
              :items="parts"
              :custom-filter="customFilter"
              item-title="name"
              item-value="code"
              single-line
            />
          </div>
        </template>
        <template #item.quantity="{ item }">
          <div class="d-flex gap-1">
            <VTextField
              v-model="item.quantity"
              label="Quantity"
              density="compact"
              single-line
            />
          </div>
        </template>
        <template #item.price="{ item }">
          <div class="d-flex gap-1">
            <span class="price-display">৳{{ getPartPrice(item.product) }}</span>
          </div>
        </template>
        <template #item.discount="{ item }">
          <div class="d-flex gap-1">
            <VTextField
              v-model="item.discount"
              label="Discount (%)"
              density="compact"
              single-line
            />
          </div>
        </template>
        <template #item.subtotal="{ item }">
          <div class="d-flex gap-1">
            <span class="subtotal-display">৳{{ calculateSubtotal(item) }}</span>
          </div>
        </template>
      </VDataTable>
```

```js
const customers = ref([])
const parts = ref([])
const items = ref([])

function addRow() {
  items.value.push({
    product: null,
    quantity: null,
    discount: null,
  })
}
```

The `addRow()` function should add a row to table which it does perfectly so that I can enter the data. For some reason when I `console.log(items.value)` it comes up empty even after I give some input. And so when I click addRow() it just keeps adding more empty objects. I am using using `<script setup>`.

Comment: The code provided so far seems to only show what has worked.  "I tried cloning the previous row but it didn't work", please show the code for this attempt.

Comment: I deleted that code and don't have it anymore. tried using JSON.stringify(). The addRow() works but when it creates the row the previously created row's inputs that I have selected/typed disappear. That's the problem. @yoduh

Comment: I don't know what you mean by you tried using JSON.stringify. Can you describe what you're trying to do step by step with some example data/values?  I'm just trying to understand _exactly_ what the expected vs actual result is.  When you click `addRow` you're trying to create a new row that is a copy of the previous row, but you're just getting a mew empty row **and** the previous row is having its data erased?  It would be preferable if you could show some code for what you're trying to do, even if it doesn't work.  It's easier to debug actual code than just descriptions of code.

Comment: I have changed my question. The clone code was just a try.. that did nothing. I just want the fix for the problem, the addRow() currently just adds a new row, so need help.

Comment: You can try without `<script setup>` - will be much easier for you.